# How can i decoding post method url?

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, ruby

i want to send an post method request without enconding anything, 
For example when i am submit this form the browser encoding the % to %25 so how can i fix it.

```
<form action="https://e.target.com/i" method="POST" >
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://m.ex.com/?t=%20" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just use a space instead of %20 inside of the attribute.

Comment: @luminoslty i know space = %20 but i need to know how can i send an post request without encoding % to %25

Comment: instead of using %20 use a space, or +, or use javascript to submit your form so you can url decode & url encode before you send your request.

Comment: You can't. The post will form encode the data and server should be decoding it

Comment: i want to send this %E5%98%8A but it's changing to %25E5%2598%258A

Comment: @charlietfl why i can't

Comment: So you are looking to send 嘊 for [CRLF injection](https://hackerone.com/reports/52042) purposes I assume? When you say submit this and encoding it, where is that occurring exactly?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, can you bypass it?

Comment: You have provided nothing showing that this occurs, where it occurs, how it occurs. So at this point in time no I cannot but if you were to provide some evidence as to what you are actually experiencing then probably. Right now the assumption is that you wish to submit the literal "%E5%98%8A" which needs to have the % encoded properly.Thus "%25"

Comment: Form-encoding will always encode `%`, you can't avoid this, so if you want to send literal `%` let it do its thing. On the receiving end this gets automatically decoded.

Comment: Stop being recalcitrant. You can't change the browser behaviour.